# Limitation of Google App Script web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I deploy a wep app with script.google.com to **only get current datetime and don't use any Action in quota table**.
Quota: https://script.google.com/dashboard/quota

My code

```
function doGet() {
    var dateTime = currentDateTime();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(dateTime);
}

function currentDateTime() {
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
}
```

I have a question: How many of requests limit if i don't use any Action in quota table?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any information/ reference about a limit on the `Utilities` service and I've just run a quick test making over a million calls to the `Utilities` service without any problem, so it's very, very high or unlimited.